# Using Becker's XPath method for more than the first element?

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to parse through an XML file, using importXML, on a Google apps spreadsheet.

My problem is that I have my XML document set up like this:

```
staffList
    staff
        name
        email
    staff
        name
    staff
        name
        email
```

and I'm trying to select all of the email elements (I tried //staff/email, but it doesn't insert null if the node does not exist), and write NULL if the node for email does not exist (like in the above example).

I tried the XPath query below, but it only is selecting the first email element, and writing into 1 row, rather than writing into n rows, where n is the number of 'staff' nodes.

=ImportXML("http://www.engr.udel.edu/mf/test_staff.xml";"concat(/staffList/staff/email, substring('not-found', 1 div not(/staffList/staff/email[node()])))")

Does anybody have any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use**:

```
//staff/email | //staff[not(email)]
```

This selects all existing `email` elements whose parent is a `staff` element ... *plus* any `staff` element that doesn't have an `email` child.

Not exactly as "returning a null" (because there is no such thing as "null" in XPath), but your code will need just to check for a `staff` element instead for a "null".

Comment: Thank You! I was trying to search for null for the longest time.  This was more counter-intuitive to me, but I can filter through the results now.